# Dispalcment modifiers coffuses normal direction

Tags: texturing, uv, normals, displacement

When I use displacemnt modyfier on the model it displaces the faces only on x axies insted of perpendicular to the face. But normals of model are set to by perpedicular.[image]
[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Try setting the strength of the displacement modifier to a negative value.

Comment: @Christopher Bennett didn't help

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for using UV coordinates as opposed to Local?

Comment: @Christopher Bennett  I'm trying to find out why my normals aren't baking properly but nobody seem to understand why that is why and also changing it to local doesn't help

Comment: I'm not sure then. It's hard to tell any further without actually seeing the project. If you want, you can upload it here, so users have a chance to look at and find the problem - https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @Christopher Bennett I found the reson I didn't set the scale roation and location

Comment: Ahhh, yes. Non-uniform scale will certainly do it

Comment: Feel free to post and accept your own answer for this, Zinek

Comment: @AllenSimpson Sorry I just selcted the object and used ctrl+a and choose to set scale location and rotation.